# Contact form 7 file attachment

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I use contact form 7.
[file file-123 limit:25m filetypes:png|jpg|jpeg|pdf]
This is the shortcode. When i upload the file and send it is just says the name of the file but not the file it self.

Comment: https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/

Comment: please show the code you have for the form not  jut the shortcode

Answer (score 2):

You need to include [file-123] on the second TAB - "Mail" in the last section "file attachments"

Also, limit needs to be like limit:25mb you are missing b, but I do not suggest to use that big attachments because most of emails have limit to 25mb

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the tag name of your field in the MAIL tab > FILE ATTACHMENTS

From your field:
 You can attach up to 2MB jpg, doc, xls, pdf or zip file
[file AttachFile limit:2mb filetypes:jpg|zip|rar|doc|pdf|xls|docx|xlsx]

The tag name is “AttachFile”. You have to add it:
Go to your WP Dashboard > Contact > Contact Forms
Click to Edit the form (which has the file attached option)
Go to Mail tab. At the bottom is File Attachments text area, add this: [AttachFile] and hit save. Then, test it. [AttachFile] must be add to the 2nd text area at bottom otherwise you will get only file name with extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do with htaccess method. this is working for me.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```